# Cocoapods frameworks.sh error: no such file

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

So I'm fairly new at both Swift and working with cocoapods, and after spending several days of researching I cannot figure out why my project isn't building. I get the following error:

(My project)/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-(My project)/Pods-(My project)-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory

I am using Xcode 7.2.1 and Cocoapods 0.39.0 and I seem to have tried all the troubleshooting tips from Cocoapods' website. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make it work?

My podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
use_frameworks!

pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'FontAwesome.swift'
pod 'Lock', '~> 1.21'
pod 'JWTDecode', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Lock-Facebook', '~> 2.1'
pod 'SimpleKeychain', '~> 0.7'
pod 'Bolts', '~> 1.6'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.1'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'Auth0', '~> 0.2'
```

Comment: Cocoapods have not been installed properly. Try reinstall pods again.

Comment: This is not specific to the Swift language, so I'm removing that tag :)

Answer (score 4):

**You're probably missing the target block for your target, in the Podfile.**

I added a target to my project, and forgot to add a target block to the Podfile for that target, and I had the same error.

> (My project)/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-(My project)/Pods-(My project)-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory

The path components are actually named after the target:
(My project)/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-[target]/Pods-[target]-frameworks.sh

Cocoapods builds configuration files for each target that you specify. Try adding a target entry to your Podfile, like so:

```
target "SOME TARGET" do
    specify pods here
end
```

If you end up adding a lot of targets, it might be a good idea to define pod groups that you can easily use inside your target entries. So, you would define your groups above your target entries, like so:

```
def commonPods
    specify pods here
end
```

Then you can use the group name in your pod entry, instead of copying all the pod entries for every target:

```
target "SOME TARGET" do
    commonPods
end
```

Adding the target entry in your Podfile will cause CocoaPods to generate a new set of files the next time you run `pod install`. However, before you run that command, you will probably need to set your configurations to `None`, so that Cocoapods can assign its own configuration. Here's how to do that:

1. Go to your project-level target
2. For each configuration listed under **Configurations**, select `None` for your target, in the drop-down menu under `Based on Configuration File`.

These steps will eliminate the Cocoapods warning that reads:

> CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all...

Once you've edited your Podfile and you nullified your configurations, you're ready to run `pod install` on the command line. After the process is completed, check back with your base configuration settings, and note that they have been set to the configuration file that was generated by CocoaPods!

I hope that helps!

Comment: So using Cocoapods is supposed to make it easy? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of dumb, but it happened to me:

You might be in the wrong directory.

I was running `pod install` from directory `Desktop/Project/Project Files`, and I kept getting an error like this.

Then I realized I was in one step too far, so I went up to directory `Desktop/Project`, and it worked.

As to why `pod install` even ran considering the Podfile was in `Desktop/Project` and not `Desktop/Project/Project Files`... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

My  problem  is that " blablabla Pods-XXXX-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory"

Firstly,  I  fix it by using  command line "pod install" , it has nothing effection.

The finally solution :
Touch "Build Phases" -> "Embed Pods Frameworks"  ,you can see the path :XXXXX.sh"
Be sure that the XXX.sh  is the same as your project's. if not, change the path.
Then  clean and build.
It's done.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running `pod install` in the same directory where you have your xcode project.